# Text is going out of bounds; prohibit the hyphenation of all words

Tags: hyphenation

I have such preamble:

```
\documentclass[bachelor, subf]{gost732}

\usepackage[a4paper,includefoot,
            left=3.5cm, right=1cm,
            top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
            headsep=1cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol]{footmisc}
\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\thechapterfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\prethechapter}{} 
\renewcommand{\postthechapter}{.~}
\renewcommand{\appendixfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsectionfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theappendixalign}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\pretheappendix}{\protect{Attachment}~} 
\renewcommand{\tocpretheappendix}{\protect{Attachment}~}
\renewcommand{\introname}{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\sectionindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\subsectionindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\aftersection}{6pt plus .1pt}
\renewcommand{\aftersubsection}{3pt plus .1pt}
\renewcommand{\conclusionname}{Conclusion}
\ifpdf\usepackage{epstopdf}\fi
\def\headfont{\small}
\pagestyle{headcenter}
\chapterpagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.\hfil}
\makeatother
\hyphenpenalty=10000
```

Text is going out of bounds. I set the right border to 1 cm, but when I prohibited the hyphenation of all words, the border increased and the text began to go out of bounds:

How to fix this problem? Please, help.

[image]

Comment: You should find in the log file what `geometry` is doing; I suspect some interaction with the class. If you're using a specialized class, you shouldn't tamper with the page parameters. Of course, disabling hyphenation will make it difficult for TeX to produce good paragraphs, particularly at 14pt size. Don't disable hyphenation and don't use font so big, unless the document is for sight impaired people.

Comment: If you really *must* suppress hyphenation, you may find it better to set the text raggedright,

Comment: `\usepackage{microtype}` might also help to mitigate some of your overfull hboxes. But basically when you suppress hyphenation, you're making TeX's job of fitting everything neatly in fixed-width lines much much harder. You can use the dreaded `\sloppy`, too. Overfull hboxes will be replaced by too much whitespace between words but when you don't want hyphenation and you don't want left-justification, you'll have to choose your poison.

Comment: \usepackage{microtype} solved the problem, thanks

Comment: @user565447 good to hear that that helped already. I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) can help to mitigate the problem and if all else fails, `\sloppy` will convert ugly overfull hboxes to ugly oversized interword spacing.